# How to click on the link by using Selenium + Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am trying to open multiple links one by one by using Selenium + Python but not able to click on each link one by one and get data from each link.

I have tried:

```
for i in range(0, 1):

    list_links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')

    i = []     

    for i in list_links:

            link = i.get_attribute('href')
            my_list = [link]
            matching = [s for s in my_list if "https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/" in s]
            str_list = list(filter(None, matching))
            print (str_list)
```

I getting this after printing above code:

```
['https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/3-BHK-1865-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Mulund-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423335383538333735']
[]
['https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/1-BHK-520-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Kandivali-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423333323636353737']
[]
['https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/2-BHK-938-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Sion-in-Mumbai&id=4d423332393937303531']
[]
['https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/2-BHK-672-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Goregaon-West-in-Mumbai&id=4d423334393532373231']
[]
['https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/3-BHK-1325-Sq-ft-Multistorey-Apartment-FOR-Sale-Madh-in-Mumbai&id=4d423236343136393731']
[]
```

For click on link tried this but didn't work:

```
for link in matching:

       link.click()
       print (link)
```

**Edit:**

I have tried:

```
for s in my_list:

    if "https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/" in s:

        print (s)
        driver.find_element[s].click()
```

Getting error: `driver.find_element[s].click() TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`.

```
or 
driver.find_elements_by_link_text(s).click()
```

Getting error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`.

Please suggest something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: _for click on link tried this but didn't work_ What did happen?  Did you get an error?

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML

Comment: @John Gordon, Error: `link.click() AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'click'`

Comment: I am getting all links from here `https://www.magicbricks.com/property-for-sale/residential-real-estate?bedroom=1,2,3,4,5,%3E5&proptype=Multistorey-Apartment,Builder-Floor-Apartment,Penthouse,Studio-Apartment,Residential-House,Villa,Residential-Plot&cityName=Mumbai`

Comment: Just check if all the links that are extracted are clickable, you can do this by checking the onClick() or similar attribute of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your list contains Strings but not Web Elements of Selenium (only after that you can do "click" action).

To do this you need to save also these objects from your `list_links` list (updated version according to "matching" links).

Code:

```
my_needed_links = []

list_links = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

# Get unique links.
for link in list_links:

    if "https://www.magicbricks.com/propertyDetails/" in link.get_attribute("href"):

        if link not in my_needed_links:

            my_needed_links.append(link)

# Go through of them and click on each.
for unique_link in my_needed_links:

    unique_link.click()
    # Switch to the tab.
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
    # Do some stuff inside tab.
    # Close the tab.
    driver.close()
    # Switch back to the main tab/window.
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

PS: Another way to do it without Web Elements: use JavaScript inside Web Driver and open links (your `matching` list) in tabs/windows.

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks, can you please give me some example. `To do this you need to save also these objects from your list_links list (updated version according to "matching" links).`